# Losing NSString

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

I'm copying an `NSString` from an `NSDictionary` into a local `NSString` using `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:]`, processing it (removing some chars) then sending it to an external object.

I've used two methods a `[[MyObject alloc] initWithString:]` and `[myObject setString:]`; neither work.

Both of them make my app crash; when I use a breakpoint on the given area I get an empty `NSString`; I use `NSLog`s from the start of the `NSString` until I send it to my object; they all show the string's correct value…

Thank you all for your valuable input :-)

Comment: What kind of crash do you get?

Comment: Also, please post the setString: and initWithString: methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:stringBeingCopied]` call with `[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:stringBeingCopied]`, creating a mutable string, as opposed to an immutable ("normal") string will stop the `setString:` calls from crashing your app

Immutable strings, being immutable, don't respond to setString: calls - which are NSString mutators. Creating an NSMutableString instead, which implements setString:, will let you modify the string object.

Comment: What is the theory behind your proposed solution?

Comment: I thought i'd just give the code that "will work" as people already explained what went wrong, but i edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> I've used two methods a [[MyObject
>   alloc] initWithString:] and [myObject
>   setString:]; neither work.

Show your work!  Can't help you without showing more code.   In particular, how did you implement `initWithString:` and `setString:` on your `MyObject` class?

Comment: I'm sorry but I would have loved to share my work but for privacy reasons I can't… Sorry…

Answer (score 0):

Strings are normally immutable. To modify a string, you need a NSMutableString. Either do `[string mutableCopy]`, or do this from inside the `initWithString` method. Maybe you do this already, but please post your code if possible. I'm afraid it's hard to give any further help without it...